# Salesforce Delete Case based on Subject

Tags: salesforce-apex

We have specific Email2Case emails that come in that we just want to delete. Below is a simple APEX trigger that I think will do the trick.

```
trigger CaseDeleteDatabaseCompaction on Case (after insert) {
List<Id> casesToDelete = new List<Id>();

    for (Case a: Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('Subject: ' + a.Subject);
        if (a.Subject == 'Error: Database compaction') 
        {
            casesToDelete.add(a.Id);
            System.debug('Adding ID: ' + a.Id);
        }

        if(casesToDelete.size()>0)
        {
            System.debug('casesToDelete: ' + casesToDelete.size());
            Database.delete(casesToDelete);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `if` should be placed outside of the loop, otherwise the `List<Id>` wouldn't make any sense.

Your code would be more readable and it would be easier to grasp at first glance if you use better names to name your things with.

Let your variables/conditions have some space to breathe, e.g `if(casesToDelete.size()>0)` is easier to read like `if(casesToDelete.size() > 0)`

Implementing the mentioned points would look like so:

```
trigger CaseDeleteDatabaseCompaction on Case (after insert) {
List<Id> casesToDelete = new List<Id>();

    for (Case currentCase: Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('Subject: ' + currentCase.Subject);
        if (a.Subject == 'Error: Database compaction') 
        {
            casesToDelete.add(currentCase.Id);
            System.debug('Adding ID: ' + currentCase.Id);
        }
    } 
    if(casesToDelete.size() > 0)
    {
        System.debug('casesToDelete: ' + casesToDelete.size());
        Database.delete(casesToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the second if statement. That should have been out side  the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that you really don't need to do any more than what Heslacher has mentioned.

That said, if you ever find yourself needing to test for more than one subject line, I might suggest moving to using a `Set<String>` in concert with a [Custom Metadata Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5).

Doing this decouples the configuration from the code that uses it, which allows you to make changes to the *specific* behavior of code without the need for a deployment (the *general* behavior of your code, delete cases where the subject matches x, y, and z, will be unchanged).

The code for that might look something like this

```
trigger CaseDeleteDatabaseCompaction on Case (after insert) {

    // You initially used a List<Id> here to get around the fact that records 
    //   stored in trigger context variables (i.e. Trigger.new and the like) are
    //   read-only in "after" triggers.
    // This likely violates the Principle of Least Astonishment, so I recommend
    //   using a List<Case> instead.
    List<Case> casesToDelete = new List<Case>();
    Set<String> targetCaseSubjects = new Set<String>();

    // Custom Metadata Types have a __mdt suffix (as opposed to __c for 
    //   custom objects and custom settings)
    // Other than that, they behave (mostly) like any ol' SObject
    // Queries for Custom Metadata Types do not count against your 100 query per-transaction
    //   governor limit (unless it involves a long text area field)
    for(Case_Delete_Subjects__mdt configuredSubject :[SELECT Subject__c FROM Case_Delete_Subjects__mdt]){
        targetCaseSubjects.add(configuredSubject.Subject__c);
    }

    for (Case currentCase: Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('Subject: ' + currentCase.Subject);

        // Set.contains() is your friend.
        // It helps to avoid long IF conditions
        // The drawback is that, unlike regular string equality using ==, contains() is
        //   case-sensitive
        if (targetCaseSubjects.contains(a.Subject)) 
        {
            // We can't directly use trigger.new with a delete DML statement
            // However, if we clone() the record in trigger.new, it becomes a 
            //   completely separate in-memory instance of the record (as opposed
            //   to a reference to the same memory location as the record in trigger.new)
            // That allows us to work around the restrictions on trigger.new
            // The clone() method is ridiculously fast, so much so that it should
            //   never be a concern for your CPU limit
            casesToDelete.add(currentCase.clone());

            // The downside of the above is that you're consuming extra heap space
            //   to store that cloned instance.
            // If heap space is an issue for you (it isn't for most people), then 
            //   you could instead use the SObject constructor method below to 
            //   achieve the same result with (potentially) a lot less heap usage
            //casesToDelete.add(new Case(Id = currentCase.Id));
            System.debug('Adding ID: ' + currentCase.Id);
        }
    }

    // The guard against performing DML on empty lists is unnecessary.
    // If there is nothing to perform DML on, Salesforce won't try to perform the DML
    //   (or, at the very least, not count it against your limits)


    // Using the Database class's dml methods is usually best reserved for cases where
    //   you want to detect and handle partial failures.
    // For most people's use-cases, the regular DML statements are just fine.
    delete casesToDelete;
}
```

Comment: But when you clone and add that clone to the list are you not just deleting the clone and not the original case?

Comment: @Gunner1714 The short answer is that _the important bit is that the clone will have the same value in the Id field_. Deleting a record, cloned via apex, will delete the underlying data that Salesforce is storing in their back-end data stores as long as the Id matches. Getting into more detail than that would be more appropriate for SFSE, and would probably make a good question over there. Just be sure to read up on "object references" and search for similar questions before asking a new one on this topic over there.